# Firebase analytics to Google analtyics (GTM) Events and Users counts

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

Experts,

I've few questions around Firebase Analytics and Google Analtytics.

I've used GTM containers to pass custom events from firebase to google analytics - it works fine. However, 
- number of events that I see in Firebase console is different than Google analytics. Would you know why?
- Similarly, number of users in firebase console is different than google analytics  - would you know why?
[GTM TAG EVENT SETUP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn1wt.png)
Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented Firebase and GTM as well and the event counts and number of users for the last 7 days were not exact, but quite similar (off by 50 out of 7500 for users).

Some screenshots of the numbers would help and also screenshots of GTM tag setup.

Comment: Thanks Kenny, Added a image see the link above please.